# WSDL page can't open on localhost IP

Tags: tomcat

I am developing banking web app and for using their web services I needed to using apache tomcat file that after running generate OTP .My terminal output after running startup.sh file is:

```
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Aug 10, 2022 10:24:58 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/7  config=null
Aug 10, 2022 10:24:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 353 ms
```

[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7MBM.png)

When I opening my localhost:8443 page I cant see WSDL page

[My browser page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWnjV.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question to contain an actual question. It's unclear what you're after "I can't see a page" is not a question as we don't know what you see. Preferably provide a [mcve]

Comment: @OlafKock added screen shot

Comment: That error message (in text) should be part of the question - Here is why you [shouldn't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). While you're at it: Your browser offers "details" - please provide them as well. It's quite typical that https on localhost requires some extra work, but we can't guess what your situation is if you don't give all of the information that's already available to you.

Comment: To phrase it differently: This is _not at all_ a problem with WSDL, but with the TLS-setup that you have for your server. And the error message's "details" in your browser might help you find an existing question or tutorial on how to achieve what you need to do. But if you don't find existing documentation, we'll need your TLS-related setup in Tomcat to help (but likely, only to point out either an already existing question - e.g. a duplicate - or to state that this is rather configuration- than programming related and - at least borderline - off-topic on stackoverflow (see [help/on-topic])

Comment: Please all add the <Connector/> elements from your server.xml file (with any passwords replaced with ***) to your question.